# Why do trailing spaces screw up a .vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I tried to do this:

```
nnoremap B ^    " comments over here
nnoremap E $    " comments over here
```

This surprised me by not working; instead the behavior of `B` and `E` became super-wonky. Then I tried getting rid of the whitespaces after these commands:

```
nnoremap B ^"     comments over here
nnoremap E $"     comments over here
```

and that fixed it. What effect were the trailing whitespaces having on these commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:help map-comments`:

```
It is not possible to put a comment after these commands, because the '"'
character is considered to be part of the {lhs} or {rhs}.
```

So… neither

```
nnoremap B ^    " comments over here
```

nor

```
nnoremap B ^"     comments over here
```

can work as expected: the first one is the equivalent of typing

```
^<space><space><space><space>"<space>comments<space>over<space>here
```

and the second one is the equivalent of typing

```
^"<space><space><space><space>comments<space>ove<space>here
```

As Roland Smith suggested, put your comment above your mapping. And avoid trailing whitespace.

Comment: And yet, `nnoremap B ^"     comments over here` *does* work as expected... Hm.

Comment: Think about what it does: jump to the first non-blank of the line then use register `<space>` to do `<space>` then whateverwhatever. Vim is just bailing out after the first weird stuff. Anyway, just don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to a remap command are;

- an optional attribute (`<buffer>`, `<silent>`,
     `<expr>`, `<script>`, `<unique>` or `<special>`)
- the left hand side
- the right hand side

Try invoking `:map` after defining your original mappings. You'll see that the spaces and comments become part of the mapping. This is probably not what you want.

Waht I would advise is to put the comment on the line before the mapping command;

```
" Format the current paragraph
nnoremap <leader>f gqap

" Toggle line numbering.
nnoremap <c-n> :set number! number?<cr>
```